# Pulling docker images from gov cloud when we are working in commercial cloud in Azure and vice-versa

Tags: azure, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, azure-gov

How can we pull ACR images from gov Cloud if we are working in commercial cloud?

Comment: You will definitely need to provide more information than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to accomplish this using *token* authentication against your ACR.  Be advised though that this is currently a preview feature and requires the **Premium** SKU for ACR.  Having said that, here are the steps:

1. [Generate an authentication token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-repository-scoped-permissions) for your ACR in Azure Government, specifying `_repositories_pull` for the scope map.  Make sure to generate the password too.  You can do this after you create the token - just click on the token in the portal and there will be an option to generate a password.
2. After you generate the password, copy the *Docker login command* that is generated.  It will look something like `docker login -u token1 -p 3AP3Gf...wJ <youracr>.azurecr.us`
3. From your terminal, where you have access to your AKS cluster in commercial, login to docker using the docker command from #2.  Note: you will probably have to run this as `sudo`.  This will generate a file at `~/.docker/config.json` that contains the password to authenticate to your ACR in Azure Gov.
4. Use the `config.json` from #3 to [create a secret based on existing Docker credentials in your cluster](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#registry-secret-existing-credentials).
5. Finally, use an `imagePullSecret` in your pod spec to use the secret you generated in #4.  Also, be sure to update your `image` to reference the full path of your container image in ACR.  [Example here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/pull-image-private-registry/#create-a-pod-that-uses-your-secret).